# Invert the timeline of an ODE with periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a ODE $$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t)),$$ 
with $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Moreover, suppose that for some initial conditions $x(0) \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the system has periodic solutions (e.g. the system has a center, the system has a stable limit cycle...).

Is it possible to rewrite this ODE in order to **invert** the time line? In other word, is it possible to find another ODE:

$$\dot{y}(s) = g(y(s)),$$

where the "dot" now stands for the derivative with respect to $s$ and $y(s) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$x(t) = y(-s),$$

provided that $y(0) \in A$?

Of course this work for linear system such that the origin is a center by choosing $g(y) = -f(y)$. Indeed:

$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x}_1 = x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 = -x_1 
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\dot{y}_1 = -y_2 \\
\dot{y}_2 = y_1 
\end{cases}.
$$

For nonlinear systems (e.g. the Van der Pol oscillator), I'm having trouble since I'm not able to solve the second system numerically.

Comment: You mean like $\dot y(t)=-\dot x(-t)=-f(x(-t))=-f(y(t))$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann good point. I was suspecting that the "minus" sign is the right way to solve the problem. Anyway, this seems to work for linear case. I've added more comments to the question in this regard.

Comment: A periodic solution is symmetric under time reversal, so it will solve either equation.  The stability of the periodic solution will be opposite for each equation however.

Comment: @Paul well,  maybe I'm experiencing just numerical problems. I suspect that for nonlinear system like the Van der Pol oscillator, which exhibit a Hopf bifurcation, the limit cycle passes from stable to unstable.

Comment: That's exactly what happens.

Comment: @Paul : There are many periodic functions that are not symmetric under time reversal.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, Is there any limit cycle which is not symmetric under time reversal?

Comment: @Paul : Please define symmetric. Even if the limit cycle is a circle $t\mapsto e^{it}$, which is quite symmetric as geometric curve, there is no simple symmetry under time reversal. Or take the limit cycle [in this system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3495136/115115), what could be the symmetry here?

Comment: Under time reversal, an $\omega$-limit cycle gets transformed to an $\alpha$-limit cycle, and vice versa.  This is a standard theorem of dynamical systems.

Comment: @Paul : That is a rather tautological version of symmetry under time reversal: The time reversed process looks like the original process moving backward in time.